# Does Java volatile variables impose a happens-before relationship before it is read?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a piece of code which looks like this:

<sub>Snippet A:</sub>

```
class Creature {
    private static long numCreated;
    public Creature() {
        synchronized (Creature.class) {
            numCreated++;
        }
    }
    public static long numCreated() {
        return numCreated;
    }
}
```

From my understanding, since reading of `numCreated` is not synchronized, if Thread-A creates a `Creature` at 1pm, and Thread-B reads `numCreated()` at 2pm, `numCreated()` may well have returned either 0 or 1 (even when Thread-A has finished initializing the object at 1.05pm).

So I added `synchronized` to `numCreated()`:

<sub>Snippet B</sub>:

```
class Creature {
    private static long numCreated;
    public Creature() {
        synchronized (Creature.class) {
            numCreated++;
        }
    }
    public static synchronized long numCreated() { // add "synchronized"
        return numCreated;
    }
}
```

and all's well, except that I was thinking, if I modify it to *Snippet C*, is the variable `numCreated` still synchronized properly?

<sub>Snippet C:</sub>

```
class Creature {
    private static volatile long numCreated; // add "volatile"
    public Creature() {
        synchronized (Creature.class) {
            numCreated++;
        }
    }
    public static long numCreated() { // remove "synchronized"
        return numCreated;
    }
}
```

With *Snippet C*, is it guaranteed that as soon as Thread-A completes object creation at 1:05pm, Thread-B's call to `numCreated()` is sure to return `1` ?

<sub>PS: I understand that in a real situation I would probably use an `AtomicLong` but this is for learning purposes</sub>

Comment: volatile reads are cheap, this is what you need to know. Yet, writes are not cheap, though. Synchronization requires both a volatile write and CAS (compare and set), plus contended monitors bail to OS which is the motivation to lock-free impl.

Comment: given the previous comment, do no try to play *smarter* by removing volatile.

Comment: @bestsss I don't understand your last comment, what do you mean by not removing volatile? (in Snippet C I was adding volatile and removing the synchronized)

Comment: It's often observed people try to remove `volatile` "to optimize". For instance, if you have synchronized write (or other memory fence) and non-volatile read, it will mostly works unless the compiler decides to optimize/cache the read access (virtually never happens). The technique is sometimes used for gathering statistics since they do not need to be super-accurate but having volatile writes will incur extra penalty to the writer (producer), AtomicXXX.lazySet is an option but it's too cumbersome for daily use.

Comment: @bestsss Heys I'm not sure I'm understanding your statement "volatile writes will incur extra penalty to the writer". Btw combining with your comment in the answer below, am I right to say that you are for *Snippet C* over *Snippet B* ?

Comment: C is much better. To have any useful concurrency the reads should be mostly non-blocking and if possible w/o writes to shared states.

Comment: the point is, when attempting to build statistics that are not used for internal usage and may not be perfectly coherent (say cache hit/miss ratio) using volatiles hurt the performance. So you can get away w/o volatile. In all other case use volatile if you read/write shared state.

Comment: @bestsss ok to clarify what you have said, you mean that if possible, don't use `synchronized`, use volatile. But if possible, don't even use volatile, use *normal* code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility:

> A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of
>   that same field. Writes and reads of volatile fields have similar
>   memory consistency effects as entering and exiting monitors, but do
>   not entail mutual exclusion locking.

So the answer is yes. The write of the volatile in the constructor happens before the read of the volatile in `numCreated()`. And since the non-atomic incrementation is still done in a synchronized block, the synchronization is alright (the incrementation is not atomic, but the write of the volatile long is).

Comment: Heys thanks for the help =D Btw could you comment on the performance of using volatile (Snippet C) as compared to the performance of using synchronized for reading (Snippet B) ? In other words, would you prefer B or C ?

Comment: I would prefer an AtomicLong, because it makes synchronization easier and the point obvious. Without ATomicLong, I would prefer snippet B because it's easier to understand and doesn't mix two synchronization strategies. The performance difference should be negligible in 99% of the cases anyway. Multi-threading is very very hard, not often approached by most developers, and not well-known. I would thus care about readability and correctness before caring about performance.

Comment: The performance of both is similar since the fix to the java memory model (version?)

Comment: @HighlandMark, well No! the volatile read is actually (almost) "free" on most hardware, while non-biased "synchronized" requires CAS+write and the difference is quite huge.

Comment: Ic. Thanks all for the help =D

Comment: I thought so, too, until I found this article: http://www.infoq.com/articles/The-OpenJDK9-Revised-Java-Memory-Model
At the end, author briefly mentions, without any form of proof, that "In light of the above, there are some simple things that can be fixed in JMM9. For example: volatile fields - a volatile field initialized in a constructor is not guaranteed to be visible even if the instance itself is visible." So, which one is true, now? :)