# Volatile writes reorder with non volatile writes

Tags: java

Does volatile writes are reordered with non volatile writes.
For Ex:
I have two threads T1 and T2:

**T1:**

```
i = 10;  
volatile boolean result = true;
```

**T2:**

```
while(!result){
}

System.out.println(i);
```

Does T2 always see the updated value of i(10) or old value?

Comment: in java, you can't do `Volatile int boolean  result = true;`.

Comment: The relevant part of JLS is [17.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.2), where volatile writes and reads are listed as sychronization actions. So, 10 must be printed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is a happens-before relationship for a volatile statement:

Please consider this stackoverflow question: [Does Java volatile variables impose a happens-before relationship before it is read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023721/does-java-volatile-variables-impose-a-happens-before-relationship-before-it-is-r)

> A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of
>   that same field. Writes and reads of volatile fields have similar
>   memory consistency effects as entering and exiting monitors, but do
>   not entail mutual exclusion locking.

Also you can read section 3.1.3 (Locking and visbility) in the great book called "Java Concurrency in Practice". There is a relevant explanation there about a similar visibility issue and the outline is this:

> Locking is not just about mutual exclusion; it is also about memory visibility.To ensure that all threads see the most up to date values of shared mutable variables, the reading and writing threads must synchronize on a common lock

In your code the lock is the volatile variable

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, this is correctly synchronized, so no races occur and 10 is always printed.

The important parts are that within a thread, things occur in program order, and that writes to a volatile variable happen before reads that see that value. Together with the transitive closure rule, this means that the assignment to i happens before the print statement.

`i = 10` happens before `result = true`. `result = true` happens before `result` is read as true in thread 2. `result` is read as true happens before `System.out.println(i);`. Therefore, `i = 10` happens before `System.out.println(i);`.